# C# StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter not properly truncating text in PrintDocument

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, printdocument

I am building a C# WinForms app, and I am working on a PrintDocument to generate an order ticket.  Each line in the order detail includes a SKU, item description, price and quantity ordered, and part of what I need to is to make sure the item description is truncated if it doesn't fit inside the RectangleF defined for it.  I have set up formatting like so:

```
StringFormat fmtNearTrimmed = new StringFormat ( );
fmtNearTrimmed.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
fmtNearTrimmed.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
fmtNearTrimmed.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisWord;
```

I am then using this in the PrintDocument (in the PrintPage event) as follows:

```
// Item Description
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle ( Pens.Black, 200, curPos, 550, defaultBoldFont.Height + 4 );
rc = new RectangleF ( 200, curPos, 550, defaultFont.Height + 4 );
e.Graphics.DrawString ( list[curItem].ProductName, defaultFont, Brushes.Black, rc, fmtNearTrimmed );
```

From everything I've read, this should work, and the text should be trimmed when it reaches the end of the rectangle.  But it doesn't.  Here's what I see:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

As you can see, the item description that is too long to fit the RectnagleF object should be truncated, but it isn't.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `StringFormat fmtNearTrimmed = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);` See also [StringFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformatflags?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)

Comment: Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable text wrapping, add the [`StringFormatFlags.NoWrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformatflags?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#fields) flag when you set the [`StringFormat.FormatFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.formatflags?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#definition) property or pass it to the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-drawing-stringformat-ctor(system-drawing-stringformatflags)) that takes this type.

```cs
var fmtNearTrimmed = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap)
{
    Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center,
    Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
};
```

Also, and according to what I see in the attached image, if you need to enable text wrapping elsewhere in this or other printing job, add the `StringFormatFlags.LineLimit` flag to skip the lines that does not perfectly printed and displayed within the formatting rectangle if its height is not high enough.